# Codeigniter - creation of a manual scheduler

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a scheduler in Codeigniter as in, at 21:24 "this" record should be updated.

I have searched a lot but the ultimate answer was to create a cron job.

Can I dynamically create cron job in Codeigniter?

Actually I was thinking to create a class in which a method will keep checking:

1. Time.
2. Anything to update.

How to create such a function most efficiently, as a request may come from `n` amount of users at random times to do a specific job at different time?

Comment: May I suggest keeping this out of normal web server functionality, write a separate executable that handles the intricacies of your scheduler and add it to cron with period of 1 minute or so?

Comment: yes thats the way i should be thinking about it.. thanks Robert.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not dynamically create cron jobs.

Instead I would have one script that is called through cron once a minute (once every 10 minutes...) and store all the jobs in a database with the time they are supposed to run.

Then in your script you can check the database and see if there are any jobs that need to run at this time exactly or between the time of the last check and now.

Comment: If i use this solution, I need to check my database every 10 seconds (it may even decrease in future). Now if number of jobs increases to do in specified time, (lets say it took more then 10 seconds to complete) how will it affect the next trigger?.. If it sounds i need to be more clear about my basics, please let me know.. :)

Comment: Can't i use EvTimer in my case? actually i tried for EvTimerbut got some installation problems

Answer (score 0):

To create a CRON job from PHP use the exec command. This should work (untested, on mobile)

```
exec(crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 0 0 0 php your_php_script.php"; } | crontab -);
```

Alternatively if you want to schedule a single job better to us the 'at' command.

Comment: No thats *nix only. You should be able to use the php exec() function to schedule a job using the windows version of cron though. Not sure syntax at cmd line but you can look into the Task Scheduler. Windows also has a version of 'at'